# Black holes as universal "anchors"?

Tags: general-relativity, black-holes, universe, singularities

I'm not a Physicist, but was watching a program about black holes. As I understand it time and space "stop" at the singularity of a black hole, which made me think of a black hole as some kind of "anchor," which sort of pins the Universe down in that neighbourhood of space, kind of like a Universal tent peg. After all if there's no time and space then there's nothing to move or move within. Could there be something in this idea perhaps as a useful analogy? I'd be happy to delete the question if it is deemed off-topic... maybe better on meta-physics, or perhaps not at all...

Comment: I agree with the answer from @Ben Crowell, but perhaps there is something more that can be said about geodesic singularities: I am no expert but maybe the dynamics from general relativity can only move singularities around (without destroying them)? This could be seen as pinning of spacetime to some degree (in a "dynamical" way), since you know that there are geodesics (i.e. trajectories) with an end pinned on the singularity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Our understanding of black holes is based on Einstein's theory of general relativity. The reason it's called "relativity" is that one of its basic principles is that all motion is relative. So a black hole, like any object, is both at rest and moving. It's at rest in a frame of reference where it's at rest, and it's moving in a frame of reference where it's moving.

The singularity inside a black hole is not actually a point in space. It acts more like a *time*, like 1492 AD. The mental picture of a black hole as a spherical event horizon surrounding a central point is not really correct. It's just a cartoonish way of thinking about it.

Comment: The collision between black holes showed that they have relative motion ..